# Is "it is a fun game" correct?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech

"It is a lot of fun," sounds correct, but not, "it is a fun game."
Isn't **fun** a *noun*? Then why is it used as an *adjective*?
I have heard this usage even by literary giants, so this cannot be a common mistake.
Should "funny" be used in stead?

**EDIT**
Moral of the story: *Fun* has become an adjective colloquially, hence it is impossible to see it as wrong.

Comment: Related: [Is "funnest" a word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4066/is-funnest-a-word)

Answer (score 14):

*Fun* is [both a noun and an adjective](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fun).

"It is a fun game" is correct English.

Comment: Additionally, "funny" means "humorous".  "It is a funny game" means the game makes people laugh.  "Fun" just means "enjoyable" or "pleasant".

Comment: What is the noun for funny-ness, by the way?

Comment: @Louis Rhys that would be "humor," I believe.

Comment: As Kosmonaut says, *fun* can function as both a noun and an adjective. But also note that a noun can be used in this position (as in *ball games*, *war games* and so on).

Comment: @psmears: Yes, although the stress would be different.

Comment: The link you gave has it as adjective, but marks as informal.

Comment: @CMR: Informal doesn't mean non-standard or wrong.

Comment: @Louis: *funniness,* meaning either humor or the quality of being humorous, is already a word, at least in American English. There may be a difference between American and British English here.