# What is the superlative of "fun"?

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree

I've seen *funniest* a few times in that context, but isn't that a derivation of *funny*? Is there a superlative of *fun* or do we really use *funniest* for the lack of one?

Comment: Err--why is "funniest" being a derivation of "funny" a problem? Are you perhaps looking for the superlative of **fun**?

Comment: I'm going to direct you to Wiktionary [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fun)--you can find these forms in a dictionary. Does this help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is “funnest” a word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4066/is-funnest-a-word)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A joke that causes the greatest mirth might be *the funniest joke*. But a party that gives the greatest enjoyment? To be informal, colloquial and non-standard, I offer *the funnest party*.

Comment: +1.  A more formal version of the second would be _the most fun party_.

Answer (score 2):

*Funniest* is the superlative of *funny* (and *funnier* is the comparative).  This is not "for lack of one"; "funniest" *is* the superlative.

*Funny* forms its superlative and comparative according to the standard rule (as in *red, redder, reddest* and *fast, faster, fastest*).  Words that do not follow this pattern (such as *good, better, best*) are termed "irregular".

Answer (score -1):

I would say *funfilled*.

> Saturday was the most funfilled day I've had this month.

Comment: If you have to use "most" before "funfilled", then "funfilled" is not a superlative form at all. It is just the positive form of another adjective, right?

Comment: No. 'Saturday was the most beautiful day of my life.'